# How to open a .html page that is static without setting up routes in Play framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I put main.scala.html in assets. And I want to open it without setting up routes because it is static.

In controllers.Application, I tried like this

```
public static Result index() {
    //return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    return redirect("assets/main/main.scala.html");

}
```

And in routes page, I tried like this

GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

GET     /*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/assets", file)

How can I fix my code to open http://localhost:9000/assets/main/main.scala.html?

Or should I try to put html files in public folder?

Comment: I wouldn't just find a different way to serve static content to the user. I'd recommend to stick to the usual way of serving content by rendering the template and file in your controller and still add a route for it. It's simpler and more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I like the usual way too, but my boss who wants to train me asked me to put html files in assets because I already made out one in usual way ;_;

Answer (score 1):

1) If it is static you should not name it as main.`scala`.html , but just `main.html` instead. (not mandatory, but just to be clear what is what)

2) As written in comment you should maintain routes via routes.conf and Controller. But you can load file as resource without using templates.

```
GET         /main               controllers.Application.publicMain

public static Result publicMain{
 return ok(Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/assets/main/main.html")).as("text/html");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not recommended, if you really want to do it, you could do as @mst suggested, or read the file and parse it as html.
for instance:

```
val html =
      """
        <html>
        <body>
         <p> Hello </p>
        </body>
        </html>
      """
    Ok(scala.xml.Unparsed(html)).as("text/html")
  }
```